# PHP MYSQL - Impossible Query? - Find "currently showing"

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table with a kind of weird date format in a column as varchar  - this is the format that the company has provided me with - the T in the middle seems to mess things up.

```
EVENTID   | EVENT_DATE      | EVENT_DURATION

1       | 2012-10-14T06:00  | 15
2       | 2012-10-14T06:15  | 11
3       | 2012-10-14T06:26  | 14    
4       | 2012-10-14T06:40  | 10
```

ect...ect

I have php code to return the current time in the exact same format (with the weird 'T' in the middle'

```
$thisin = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d\TH:i', date('Y-m-d\TH:i')); 
$thisin->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
$thisout= $thisin->format('Y-m-d\TH:i');
```

Assuming that today is the 14th and the current time is 06:21, how do i query the current row based on duration that matches "$thisout from php" and the next five rows (in the future).

Because the current time and date are returned from php as "2012-10-14T06:21" The query should output

```
2   | 2012-10-14T06:15  | 11        (Now SHowing)
3   | 2012-10-14T06:26  | 14    
4   | 2012-10-14T06:40  | 10
```

ect ect

I have been scratching my head for hours, DATE_FORMAT() Doesn't seem to work, and I think it may be the T in the middle. I am aslo have to figure out how to use duration to determine if the current time applies to a specific row.

This does not work

```
SELECT DISTINCT EVENTID, EVENT DATE, EVENT_DURATION 
FROM epg_event
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(EVENT_DATE, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%i') >= DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%i') 
ORDER BY EVENT_DATE ASC LIMIT 5
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: Just a note: The "weird date format" is the international standard ISO 8601 (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Combined_date_and_time_representations)

Comment: Its absolutly normal date time format.. if you compare it with NOW() it will work and this is MYSQL query only .. NO PHP needed :)

Comment: Dugh me, The query works great now, but it pulls greater than or equal to, since it will almost never greater than, how can also pull one row preceeding the query? Or else it just shows whats on next.

Comment: try `Now minus 1 second` :) i.e. if you looking for `08:50` you can look for `08:49:59`

Answer (score 0):

You should load the date information into a Date column rather than a varchar column in the database. As previously noted this is the ISO format for dates.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not currently able to test it, but something like this might work:

```
SELECT DISTINCT EVENTID, EVENT_DATE, EVENT_DURATION 
FROM epg_event
WHERE (event_date <= NOW()) AND (ADDTIME(event_date, INTERVAL event_duration MINUTE) >= NOW()) 
ORDER BY event_date ASC LIMIT 5
```

`DATE_FORMAT()` is meant for formatting a `DATETIME` field, not the other way around. And, as mentioned earlier, you event_date should be a DATETIME field and you should convert the time when you import the data to your database.

Answer (score 0):

Need to add in the interval.

```
where event_date + INTERVAL duration MINUTE >= NOW()
```